# VB.NET evaluate exception when filtering DataGridView using a Combobox and a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am trying to search through my DGV using a Combobox to get the name for the Column and textbox for the search query. I used this code before, and it worked, but now I get an `EvaluateException` saying

> Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Double and System.String.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView()
Dim CmSi = cmbSearch.SelectedItem
dv.Table = OutGoingDataSet.outgoingdeliveries
dv.RowFilter = CmSi & " Like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
OutgoingDataGridView.DataSource = dv
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the data type of values inside the cmbSearch.SelectedItem?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa the names of the column. which are `TransactionNumber` and `Posted`

Comment: You should really consider turning option strict on...

Comment: @WozzeC I'm sorry I'm still learning but what is Option Strict?

Comment: @AlexLuthor Option strict basically forces you to write your code properly. For example you have Dim CmSi and you use it as a string. But it is actually a combobox item. Your code will work since strict off is a happy fellow and uses the items tostring function, while you can be happily ignorant. Option strict forces you to turn selected item into a string otherwise it flags an error. Thus, you will always know that CmSi will be a string.

Comment: @WozzeC ohhh now I understand thank you, I will be sure to keep that in mind... How bout my problem? Could you help me with that, if you won't mind? Thanks. I've been searching the net for hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem. When you apply your filter you do this check:

```
Column LIKE 'String'.
```

This will work for all columns that are containing strings. Doubles will not work since they are not strings. Basically this would be like

```
if (5 == "5")
```

which of course is false.

So you have to convert your double to a string before doing a `LIKE` comparison. I cannot tell if it will work or not, but I reckon it will.

```
dv.RowFilter = "CONVERT(" & CmSi & ", System.String) LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
```

Comment: yup I knew that was the problem but I tried that convert and maybe I used it wrong. I'll try using your sample... Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: Thank you it worked pretty well... I did use it wrong. what I did was `"Convert System.String(Query)".